# Multiple Inheritance in orientdb vertex classes?

Tags: orientdb

I'm curious about multiple inheritance in OrientDB... say I create the following vertex classes:

```
CREATE CLASS A EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY A.label STRING

CREATE CLASS B EXTENDS A
CREATE PROPERTY B.foo STRING

CREATE CLASS C EXTENDS A
CREATE PROPERTY C.bar STRING
```

Classes B and C inherit the properties from A... so if I create a new class that inherits from both B and C:

```
CREATE CLASS D EXTENDS B,C
```

I get a resulting class D with the following properties:

```
D.label
D.label
D.foo
D.bar
```

OrientDB lets this happen with no complaints, but I am not sure how one would distinguish one 'label' property from the other in a query.

If I were to try and create a new property directly that has the same name as an existing one, such as:

```
CREATE PROPERTY C.label STRING
```

I will get an error because that property already exists.

So, is this a bug in multiple inheritance model of OrientDB?  Would it make sense for OrientDB to remove the duplicate entry, or throw an error and disallow the creation of the class?

Comment: I think you can ask on github if it's a correct behaviour

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.x, OrientDB multiple inheritance keeps one property, if more than one class have the same property in inheritance hierarchy. For example:

```
create class yClass
create property yClass.groupId STRING (MANDATRY TRUE)

create class zClass
create property zClass.groupId STRING (MANDATORY TRUE)

create class aClass extends yclass,zClass
```

aClass has one property 'groupId' (the UI may show 2 bit there is actually one)

The above can be verified:

```
create class yClass
create property yClass.groupId STRING (MANDATRY TRUE)

create class zClass
create property zClass.groupId INTEGER (MANDATORY TRUE)

create class aClass extends yclass,zClass
```

It would result in an error.

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Properties conflict detected: 'groupId (type=STRING)] vs [groupId (type=INTEGER)] DB name="testclient_com_GDB"
```

Therefore, one property is kept; if there are more than one super class, then their common properties also must have the same data type.